# Bearer Token throws EOF for one of the Threads

Tags: jmeter, bearer-token

When i tried to run the Thread group using Throughput controller facing the following issues.
**Issue# 1:** For 1 Thread - Gives error Bearer Token

**Issue# 2:** Even though Thread Group time is 10 min's. Test Runs continuously and even though i stopped , it won't stop. I have to do kill.

**Here is the Test Plan Design**

Thread Group:- Stepping Thread Group with 5 Users

Scenario#:
1.Login (Returns the Bearer Token and saved into file using Bean Shell)
2.Action(Requests gets the Bearer token from #1)
3.Logout

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) for reading the token from the file and it returns the default value of the [`csvdataset.eofstring` property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#csv_dataset) when the end of file is reached.

Depending on what you're trying to achieve when you're running out of tokens you could do one of the following:

1. If you want to continue sending the tokens which are defined in the CSV file set "Recycle on EOF" to `True` and "Stop thread on EOF" to `False`

   [image]
2. If you want to use all the tokens from CSV and then stop test - set the above parameters to the opposite values
3. If you want to use all the tokens and then continue executing other Samplers - put the token using logic under the [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) and use the following [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) as the condition: `{__jexl3("${access_token_dh}" != "<EOF>",)}`

---

In addition:

- [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)
- You can use [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/) for passing values between thread groups

Comment: From your comments #1  was already configured. # 3 Applied and failed again <EOF> .Please see the bottom screenshots

Comment: @ Dmitri, I have tried Inter-Thread Communication Plugin, but no luck Please see the bottom screenshots